# Как задать проверку в viewDidLoad на экран девайса?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

как задать проверку в viewDidLoad на экран девайса? чтоб если обычный экран то ставим 320х480, если ретина то 640х960, и если 5-й айфон то 640х1136

Comment: BOOL iPhone5 = ([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height > 480.0);

Comment: возможно вам и не нужно определять размер экрана девайса, опишите, какая у вас задача ? надо подгрузить нужную картинку?

Comment: Именно так, мне нужно подгрузить нужную картинкую, я делал их 2х видов, обычные(150х100) и двойные (300х200). мне не понятно что делать чтоб подгружались именно те которые должны подгружаться. то же и бекграунда касаеться! чтоб грузились бекграунды определённого размера, под девайс

Comment: Что-то тут я не понял, зачем? Девайс сам определяет что ему грузить, низкого качетва картинку делаешь pic.png, более высокого pic@2x.png... и все

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу просто строчкой, которая возвращает Модель девайса и Размер экрана :) дальше сам:

```
_labelIphone.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", [UIDevice currentDevice].model, NSStringFromCGRect([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)];
```

Класс UIDevice - знает все о девайсе

Класс UIScreen - знает все о текущем экране

PS: кстати это есть при создании Master-Detail проекта :) Аппл сам там пример приводит, как определить девайс.

Comment: NSString *LabelIphone;
    LabelIphone = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", [UIDevice currentDevice].model, NSStringFromCGRect([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds)];
    NSLog(@"%@",LabelIphone);     когда на ipod 4 тестирую : 2014-06-03 15:43:48.129 ChangeView01[780:707] iPod touch
{{0, 0}, {320, 480}}
не могу врубиться никак! ведь ipod то имеет 960x640

подскажите please )))

Comment: Ух, iPod тут я не в курсе :), а что говорит uidevice?

Comment: у меня именно 4-й .  получаеться нужно if-чик написать, что если UIScreen bounds = (320, 480) тогда BigImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"08.png"]; else BigImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"08@2x.png"];
а в бекграунде я сам выставлял картинку 960х640. хотя наверное панимаю что нужно кодом вставлять.